# Name for logical algebra in which $A \lor B = A + B - AB$?

Tags: probability-theory, propositional-calculus, boolean

An [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2244251/1140344) from 5 years ago provides simple rules for converting logical propositions to ordinary elementary algebraic expressions:

$$\lnot{A} = 1 - A$$
$$A \land B = AB$$
$$A \lor B = A + B - AB$$

Where $A$ and $B$ can only take on values 1 for "TRUE" and 0 for "FALSE", so $A^2 = A$, $A^2B = AB$.

Is there a commonly used name for this set of rules?  It is not Boolean Algebra because in Boolean Algebra the rules of elementary algebra do not apply.  $A \lor B \equiv A + B; 1 + 1 = 1$.  It is not exactly GF(2) (i.e., integer arithmetic modulo two) because I am using the "minus" sign.

I ask because I am writing a basic introduction to probability from a Jaynesian/Keynesian point of view and want to go straight from logic to probability without going through set theory a la Kolmogorov.  I gather that the above rules are widely used in programming languages where GF(2) is not implemented.[See the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). If there is no accepted name for this, I will just call it "converting logical propositions to ordinary algebra limited to 0/1 variables".

Comment: What is the set of values in this algebra? What is the set of operations?

Comment: Please see the previous question / answer from 5 years ago.  The question was whether we can convert a logical expression using AND, OR, and NOT into an elementary expression (using the rules of high school algebra) with the additional requirement that variables are limited to being either 1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE.  According to the answers and the Wikipedia link, this is done all the time by programmers.  I am  asking if it has a name, otherwise I will call it "converting logical expressions to ordinary algebra on 0/1 variables".  It's almost the same as GF(2) with "+" meaning XOR.

Comment: There's an equivalent version in which truth values are the two equivalence classes mod 2, with 1 mod 2 being "true" and 0 mod 2 being "false". For this one doesn't need subtraction. [not x] is 1+x, [x and y] is xy, [x or y] is x+y+xy. [also xx=x] Somewhere I read of this version as  "mod 2" polynomials.

Comment: Yes.  According to the Wikipedia article, that's GF(2) or Z mod 2.  The article recommends continuing to use "minus" "when using a programming language in which GF(2) is not implemented".  The old question from 5 years ago mentioned  polynomials and an answer mentioned boolean and Zhegalkin polynomials.

Comment: $\langle \{ 0, 1 \}, \land, \lor, \lnot \rangle$ constitutes a Boolean algebra. The expressions on the right hand sides, like $A + B - AB$ are expressions on $\mathbb{R}$; that's why you can use minus.

Comment: I was converting logical expressions into ordinary high school algebra on 0/1 variables.  This is not modern Boolean Algebra in which $A \lor B \equiv A + B$, but it may be closer to what Boole actually presented in his ``Laws of Thought'' (1853).  It is equivalent to arithmetic modulo 2 and is commonly done in computer programming. Since the variables $A, B, ...$  can only take on the values 1 or 0, $A^2 = A$ and $A^2B^3 = AB$.  If $P(\cdot)$ converts a 0/1 proposition to its probability between 0 and 1, apply $P(\cdot)$ to these algebraic expressions and get the properties of probability.

Comment: I gave up on allowing $A$ and $B$ to represent either TRUE/FALSE propositions or algebraic 1/0 indicators.  The 0/1 indicator for proposition $A$ is either $I(A)$ or $I_A$.  This is the same as Blitzstein and Hwang.

Answer (score 2):

After 1 month, I am answering my own question.  I found a 1981 [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689628) by Theodore Hailperin called "Boole's Algebra Isn't Boolean Algebra".  I also read some of Hailperin's 1986 book, "Boole's Logic and Probability". However, I am hestitant to refer to the system that I use as "Boole's Algebra".

Norman Wildberger's YouTube channel has a series of videos distinguishing the "Algebra of Boole" from Boolean Algebra.  Wildberger's "Algebra of Boole" is arithmetic modulo 2 in which "+" means XOR and 1 + 1 = 0.  In modern Boolean Algebra, "+" means (inclusive) OR and 1 + 1 = 1. I prefer Wildberger's "Algebra of Boole" to Boolean Algebra, but the system that I am using is neither.

I am now following Blitztein and Hwang more closely and introducing an indicator function $I(\cdot)$ that converts logical statements into ordinary high school algebraic expressions on 0/1 variables. The 0/1 variable corresponding to proposition $A$ is written $I(A)$ or $I_A$.  I gave up on allowing $A$ to represent *either* a logical proposition or an algebraic 0/1 variable.

Ordinary algebra allows the "-" (minus) sign and 1 + 1 = 2.  Since the variables are limited to 0 and 1, and since $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$, $I_A^2 = I_A$.

This system works fine and translates directly into probability rules.  For example, here is how I present the XOR probability rule:

\begin{align*}
(A \text{ XOR } B) &\equiv (A \cap \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \cap B)\\
I(A \text{ XOR } B) &= I_A(1-I_B) + (1-I_A)I_B - I_A(1-I_B)(1-I_A)I_B\\
&= I_A-I_AI_B + I_B-I_AI_B - 0\\
&= I_A + I_B - 2I_AI_B\\
P(A \text{ XOR } B) &= P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)
\end{align*}

The last step uses $P(\cdot)$ to take indicator variables to probabilities.  Like the expectation operator $E(\cdot)$, it only works on expressions that are linear in the indicator variable, so $P(I_AI_B) \neq P(A)P(B)$; instead $P(I_AI_B) = P(A \cap B)$.
Blitzstein and Hwang do something similar and call it the "Fundamental Bridge".  This avoids having the "+" sign mean two different things.  In Boolean expressions, I use "$\cup$" and reserve the "+" sign to mean what we all learned in elementary school.